# CreateProcess( ) doesn't create a new window with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag - C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, batch-file, process

I've been trying to create a process with CreateProcess() using the Windows API  of course. I haven't been able to create a new console for some reason even after scouring the web.

**Reasearch I've Done :**

I used the MSDN example code as a base for the parameters I should use in the function :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I read the following MSDN article for information on how you should create new console windows :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I also read a similar SO problem to mine about someone having the same problem :

[CreateProcess does not create additional console windows under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958276/createprocess-does-not-create-additional-console-windows-under-windows-7)

**Results :**

I've written the code I will post below with all the requirements needed to create a new console, but it doesn't behave as expected. I've spent a long time trying to find the answer on my own, but the articles above were the only relevant ones I could find through google. What happens is that the process is created, but it is inside my C program's console. I want to be able to create the process without it inherting my program's console.

There are also other discrepancies as well. If I print lots of characters in my do-while loop without a Sleep() to slow it down, TerminateProcess() will fail with Access Denied and the program will crash when I press the escape key. This is also not desired behavior.

Here is the C program that I have right now :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define IS_PRESSED( vk ) ( GetAsyncKeyState( vk ) & 0x8000 )

typedef struct process
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION p_info;
    STARTUPINFO s_info;
} process;

void win_error( char * message, int is_exit )
{

    char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
    DWORD error_code = GetLastError( );

    FormatMessage
    (
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        error_code,
        MAKELANGID( LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT ),
        ( LPTSTR ) buffer,
        BUFSIZ,
        NULL
    );

    MessageBox( NULL, buffer, message, MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK );

    if ( is_exit ) exit( error_code );

    return;
}

int create_process( process * p, const char * exe_path, const char * cmd_line_args )
{
    p->s_info.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFO );
    p->s_info.dwFlags |= CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

    return CreateProcess(
                            exe_path,
                            ( LPSTR )cmd_line_args,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            FALSE,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            &p->s_info,
                            &p->p_info
                        );
}

int main( )
{
    process p = { { 0 }, { 0 } };

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    if ( !create_process( &p, "J:\\C programs and compiliers\\C\\WindowsTest\\bin\\Debug\\matrix.bat", NULL ) )
        win_error( "CreateProcess", 1 );

    CloseHandle( p.p_info.hThread );

    do
    {
        if ( IS_PRESSED( VK_ESCAPE ) )
            if ( !TerminateProcess( p.p_info.hProcess, 0 ) )
                win_error( "TerminateProcess", 0 );

        Sleep( 50 );

    } while ( WaitForSingleObject( p.p_info.hProcess, 0 ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 );

    CloseHandle( p.p_info.hProcess );

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Batch program I'm calling :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:start
echo Hello PSAPI on Windows...
pause >nul
exit
```

I'm expecting someone will know how to mess with processes more than I do. This is my first time using the CreateProcess() function. Yes, I am aware of ShellExecute(). I am also aware that my Batch file isn't a matrix, but I wanted to start simple.

Comment: I just found the solution, but I don't have enough reputation to post it. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: You don't need reputation points to post an answer.  You can post an answer to your own question, you just won't get any reputation points for doing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` is a flag of `CreateProcess()` itself, not of `STARTUPINFO`.  You are putting the flag in the wrong place.  Try this instead:

```
int create_process( process * p, const char * exe_path, const char * cmd_line_args )
{
    ...
    return CreateProcessA(
                            exe_path,
                            cmd_line_args,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            FALSE,
                            CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, // <-- here
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            &p->s_info,
                            &p->p_info
                        );
}
```

Also, keep in mind that a `STARTUPINFOEX` can be passed to `CreateProcess()`, so your `create_process()` function should not be forcing `p->s_info.cb`, that should be the caller's responsibility depending on whether a `STARTUPINFO` or a `STARTUPINFOEX` is being used.