# How to open separate command prompt consoles for two seperate CreateProcess() API calls

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmd, createprocess

I've a caller.EXE from within which I do 2 calls of "CreateProcess() APIs like this. Both the CReateProcess() APIs are trying to launch console application EXEs.

```
Caller.cpp (Caller.EXE) has teh following code in it::
...................
..................
CReateProcess( Callee_1) // For launching a console EXE which starts running in the same CMD prompt window where I've the main "CAller.EXE" running.
..............
<Few lines of C++ logic>
........
CReateProcess(Callee_2) // For launching another console EXE .
```

Now the problem is that I want the 2nd `CreateProcess(Callee_2)` call to actually launch a different command prompt but what is happening here is that the 2nd `CreateProcess(Callee_2)` call is not launching anotehr CMD prompt. The same CMD prompt is execiting the `Callee_1` in it.

I see that in my Caller code `CreateProcess()` is successful for both the times.

I want the 2nd `CreateProcess(Callee_2)` call to actually
launch a different command prompt. How do I achieve that? I think I
should give it as part of the input parameters to
`CreatyeProcess(Callee_2)` call.

Comment: how is this tagged `c`?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to accomplish, do you want to actually launch `cmd.exe`? Or do you just want the system to open a window for you for the standard output of the new process?

Comment: Both the CReateProcess() APIs calls are trying to launch console application EXEs. Hence I want 2 different CMD consoels open where bothe "Callee_1 & Callee_2" would dump their console outputs in 2 separate CMD prompts (Consoles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very knowledgeable about Windows or MSDN, but as far as I remember,

```
CReateProcess( Callee_1)
```

which should actually be `CreateProcess()`, taken one parameter `DWORD fdwCreate` , where,

```
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
```

can be used to specify that the new process should have a new console, instead of inheriting the parent's console.

Maybe [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908775.aspx) link is helpful to you.

Comment: I observe inconsistent behavior with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE. If I use it in 1st CreateProcess(Callee_1) it does create a new console but it doesn't in the 2nd CreateProcess(CAllee_2) call ?  Is there any limit on the no: of consoles that can be opened ?

Comment: @codeLover as I told, i'm not much knowledgeable in this, so I'm not sure, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20692490/3137699) might help you.