# Start CMD in CMD with CreateProcessWithTokenW

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I have a console application which calls the `CreateProcessWithTokenW()` WinAPI function to create a new process which starts a cmd console. By calling it, it starts a new CMD Window. I want to spawn another cmd within the calling cmd window (not in a new window).

So I want to simulate the same behavior like if you start cmd and type "cmd".

```
ret = CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Comment: **A console process can use the CreateProcess function with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE to create a console process with a new console.** For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:[Creation of a Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creation-of-a-console). Here is a similar question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692490/createprocess-doesnt-create-a-new-window-with-create-new-console-flag-c-c

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal reproducible code snippet.
I added CreateProcess instead of CreateProcessWithToken....if i define 0 for 5th argument (dwCreationFlag) than it starts the CMD in the Powershell. But for CreateProcessWithToken the behavior is not the same.

Run this code with a elevated powershell (because it needs Se_Debug_Priv)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <WinBase.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <tchar.h> 

int main() {
    //DEFINE HERE PID OF winlogon.exe
    DWORD pid = 940;

    HANDLE currentProcess = {};
    HANDLE AccessToken = {};
    currentProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, TRUE, pid);
    OpenProcessToken(currentProcess, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY, &AccessToken);
    HANDLE pToken = AccessToken;
    SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL seImpersonateLevel = SecurityImpersonation;
    TOKEN_TYPE tokenType = TokenPrimary;
    HANDLE pNewToken = new HANDLE;
    DuplicateTokenEx(pToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, seImpersonateLevel, tokenType, &pNewToken);
    STARTUPINFO si = {};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

    //TEST1
    //Creates a new window for both functions so the 5th seems to be ignored 
    CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"cmds.bat", NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    //TEST2
    //Create a new windows, assumed behavior
    CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    //Creates also a new window, NOT assumed behavior
    CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag:

> CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
>   0x00000010
>
> **The new process has a new console, instead of inheriting the parent's console.** This flag cannot be used with the DETACHED_PROCESS flag.
>
> This flag is enabled by default.

That flash is what is forcing a new CMD window to be created. Without that, the new process will be created in the existing CMD window of the calling process.

Comment: ret = CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi); or ret = CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi); have the same behavior like with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE Flag.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you should use `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. According to the code:

`ret = CreateProcessWithTokenW(pNewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`

The problem is not with the use of `CreateProcessWithTokenW ()` winapi. Could you please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.

Here is the code:

```
STARTUPINFOEX startup_info = {};
PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info = {};
BOOL CreateProcTokenRes = FALSE;

CreateProcTokenRes = CreateProcessWithTokenW(NewToken, 0, L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startup_info, &process_info);

if (!CreateProcTokenRes)
{
    _tprintf(L"Cannot Create Process With Token. Failed with Error Code: %d\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(NewToken);
```

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:https://niiconsulting.com/checkmate/2019/11/token-manipulation-attacks-part-2-process-of-impersonation/

Comment: to clearify: i dont want the behavior of CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE.....it want it spawned within the existing/calling cmd/powershell. I read that i have to set the flag to 0. With the Function CreateProcess it works great, but CreateProcessWithToken seems to ignore this.